# ActionBar Home button - hide fragment and clear back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-homebutton

I would like to implement Home/Up button in the `actionBar`. I have simple application with one Activity (**A**) and two fragments (Settings (**B**) and About (**C**)).

In the other questions I have found to use `popBackStack`, but that's not the solution bacause if user goes A > B > C > B > C, back-button goes C > B > C > B > A (is this correct behaviour?).

```
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // get preferences fragment
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_about:
            // get about fragment
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, new AboutFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            // clear back stack and show home screen?

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            return true;
    }
```

I would need last case to hide any fragment (show main activity window) and clear my back stack - go home, not back. How could I achieve that?

I use AppCompat library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 private void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
         manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

or call

```
mFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Form the documentation POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE is

> Flag for popBackStack(String, int) and popBackStack(int, int): If set,
>   and the name or ID of a back stack entry has been supplied, then all
>   matching entries will be consumed until one that doesn't match is
>   found or the bottom of the stack is reached.

Comment: Thank you, I just had to use `getFragmentManager` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager` otherwise my backstack count was zero.